# jQuery no loading on a very simple HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very simple HTML page

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <script>
    $("#selector").hover(function() {
        $("#selector").toggleClass("green");
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

But I constantly get the error ReferenceError: $ is not defined - it seems not to load jQuery at any time? I tried moving it up and down, chnaged versions and sources, any ideas why it does not load?

http://jsfiddle.net/evpwjaLa/

It works on the fiddle though, not on my local comp

Comment: why are you loading 2 versions of jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the following line does something on you local host but not on jsfiddle:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min"></script>
```

BTW, are you trying to include two different versions of jQuery in the same page? And isn't the `.js` missing in the file name?

Comment: wow.. from all the things I though about, I did not notice the .js missing.. A MASSIVE THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the link to the jQuery library is wrong. This works on my computer:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- I always use this link when I'm using jQuery library :) -->
</head>
<body>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

<script>
$("#selector").hover(function () {  $("#selector").toggleClass("green");     });
</script>
</body>
```

Please note, that you included jQuery twice in your document.

Comment: The link to the jQuery library on the Google CDN looks fine to me. It uses a protocol-relative URI, which is the way to go to support HTTP as well as HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You have include two jquery files, No need to add two jquery files.

Remove:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min"></script>
```

Updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/evpwjaLa/1/